# ARC and ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, asihttprequest, automatic-ref-counting

I have a strange problem.

I use `ASIHTTPRequest` in a iOS 5 project with ARC enabled. Since `ASIHTTPRequest` does not support ARC I have disabled ARC on all individual `ASIHTTPRequest` files.

[image]

However, when I'm trying to compile my project, xcode still believes that those files are ARC-enabled and it complains.

[image]

Did I do anything wrong or is that a bug in xcode? Don't tell me to convert `ASIHTTPRequest` to ARC-compatible code with the refactor tool. I have tried to do that and xcode complains on that ARC is enabled on the project (?!?!).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You typed `-fno-ojbc-arc`. The correct flag is `-fno-objc-arc`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm blinded some times.

Comment: Glad to help. Maybe you didn't yet fully recovered from new year's eve ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I did it this way.

You have to make the ASIHTTP as a library and include it in your project.

Following is the procedure.

> 1. Create iPhone Project Cocoa Touch Static Library.
> 2. Copy all the ASIHTTP supported files and Rechability .h and .m files inside the Library  Project.
> 3. Make a Build.
> 4. You will get a .a file.
> 5. Copy the file in your project.
> 6. Copy the necessary .h (header) files you are going to use in your project.

You will not get any ARC Error.  Hope it helps some one facing similar ARC problems..