# Does ASIHTTPRequest support ARC?

Tags: ios

I have to make a rest web service call from my ios app, earlier I used ASIHTTPRequest with no ARC in xcode4, but now I have enabled ARC in my app in xcode4.2, please suggest what should I do? is there anything else which i can use to perform web service call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're including the ASI source in your project, then mark the ASI files with `-fno-objc-arc` in the compile settings for each file. If you're including it as a static library, then you don't need to do anything.

Note that if there are method calls in ASI that don't obey the naming conventions for ownership (e.g. copy/new/alloc etc...) they you'll need to bridge some of the arguments in your method calls.

Check out the following section of this article for more info: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/#third-party-libraries

Comment: Also, check out this question where someone else is using ASIHTTPRequest with ARC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694738/arc-and-asihttprequest

Comment: Note - ASIHTTP is not being updated any more, you should ideally find another library instead.  E.g. AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking