# How to build single .a (Cocoa Touch Static Library)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4

I have a Objective-C Cocoa Touch Static Library, which (depending on the schema/target - i.e. MyProject > iOS Device or MyProject > iPhone 5.1 Simulator) builds specific libMyProject.a archive which I can re-use/share with other projects.
Generally it works fine, however, I have to build for iPhone 5.1 Simulator and use this libMyProject.a in another project but *only* if this other project is going to run in Simulator. If attempt to use this .a but build the other project for iOS Device I am getting build errors claiming that library was not built/linked for this project settings.

So the question is, how do I build "unified" Cocoat Touch Static Library's libMyProject.a which I can re-use in other projects regardless how I build the other project?

I hope this all makes sense, or if not, I'll be happy to clarify.

Thanks.

Comment: I have given a procedure to do a static library for ASIHTTP check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694738/arc-and-asihttprequest/10782112#10782112 this may help for you...

Comment: Did you try searching SO before you posted this question? There are many on the same topic. Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793392/how-do-i-compile-a-static-library-fat-for-armv6-armv7-and-i386 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [iOS Universal Framework on GitHub](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework).

Comment: This did not work for me.  I ran the install script, but it did not appear as a project template in the New Project dialog.